# How to objcopy a bin file as part of a Zig build script

Tags: zig

How can I export a binary output from my elf output as part of my Zig build process?
This should happen as part of the default build command `zig build`.

I am using Zig 0.11.

My `build.zig` contains the code below. I have added comments to describe what I *think* should be happening.

```
const std = @import("std");
const Builder = std.build.Builder;

pub fn build(b: *Builder) void {
    const optimization = std.builtin.OptimizeMode.ReleaseFast;
    const cpu_model = &std.Target.arm.cpu.cortex_m0;

    // elf should be a build step that emits output.elf
    const elf = b.addExecutable(.{
        .name = "output.elf",
        .root_source_file = .{ .path = "src/startup.zig" },
        .target = .{
            .cpu_arch = .thumb,
            .os_tag = .freestanding,
            .abi = .none,
            .cpu_model = .{ .explicit = cpu_model },
        },
        .optimize = optimization,
    });

    elf.setLinkerScript(.{ .path = "src/STM32Z/MCU/STM32L052.ld" });
    
    // bin should be a build step that objcopy's output.bin from output.elf
    const bin = b.addObjCopy(.{ elf.getEmittedBin(), .{
        .format = .bin,
    });
    // This step requires output.elf to exist
    bin.step.dependOn(&elf.step);
    
    // This is the step that I want to be completed when I run `zig build`.
    // I would expect zig build to generate the elf and then the bin file
    b.default_step = &bin.step;
}
```

This builds with no error at all. Yet a zig-out directory is not created, so I cannot find either `output.elf` or `output.bi`.

I'm not really clear on:

1. If `elf.getEmittedBin()` is the correct thing to pass into the `b.addObjCopy` method
2. How to debug what steps are getting run at all.
3. How to declare what my output artifact is and where it should go. I assume I have to somehow specify that output.bin is the thing I want.

Sorry for the wall of text - I'm just feeling a bit stumped here.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I was actually pretty close to the solution.

I just needed a step to copy the bin file to my `zig-out` directory. This step was `b.addInstallBinFile(bin.getOutput(), "output.bin");`

I was mostly confused with the nomenclature here - the build outputs seem to be referred to as "install artifacts" or "install files". This makes some sense in hindsight.

My full final build script here:

```
const std = @import("std");
const Builder = std.build.Builder;

pub fn build(b: *Builder) void {
    const optimization = std.builtin.OptimizeMode.ReleaseSmall;
    const cpu_model = &std.Target.arm.cpu.cortex_m0;

    // Build the elf
    const elf = b.addExecutable(.{
        .name = "output.elf",
        .root_source_file = .{ .path = "src/startup.zig" },
        .target = .{
            .cpu_arch = .thumb,
            .os_tag = .freestanding,
            .abi = .none,
            .cpu_model = .{ .explicit = cpu_model },
        },
        .optimize = optimization,
        .single_threaded = true,
    });
    elf.setLinkerScript(.{ .path = "src/STM32Z/MCU/STM32L052.ld" });

    // Copy the elf to the output directory.
    const copy_elf = b.addInstallArtifact(elf, .{});
    b.default_step.dependOn(&copy_elf.step);

    // Copy the bin out of the elf
    const bin = b.addObjCopy(elf.getEmittedBin(), .{
        .format = .bin,
    });
    bin.step.dependOn(&elf.step);

    // Copy the bin to the output directory
    const copy_bin = b.addInstallBinFile(bin.getOutput(), "output.bin");
    b.default_step.dependOn(&copy_bin.step);
}
```